# Calculating the order of a matrix when speaking of groups

Tags: matrices, group-theory

How should I calculate the order of a matrix when speaking of groups?
For example I have the following matrix:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$

How should I calculate its order?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Its square is the identity matrix…

Comment: but why? should I square it until i get $I_{3\times 3}$? what if I have a difficult matrix that we need to square 200 time until we get $I_{3\times 3}$? is there a better/faster way?

Comment: For **any** group, if you have an element $g\neq e_G$ such $g^2=e_G$, the order of $g$ is $2$. And what you should do is to compute the **powers** of the matrix, not to keep on squaring them. The use of the Jordan normal form may be helpful here.

Comment: ok, so for my example the order of the matrix is 2 right (because $M^2=I$)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Is it possible that the order of a matrix is infinity? by your logic, there is no $n\in \mathbb{N}$ so $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^n = I$. So we get $o(M)=\infty$. is it correct?

Comment: That is correct too.